# JMockit MockUp multiple methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

Is it possible to create a JMockit MockUp with multiple methods? (more specifically: 1 constructor and 1 method). I have tried the following two approaches, but in neither case the mock of myMethod is called (the original method is called instead). The mock of the constructor is called in both approaches. Am I doing something wrong? Using an @Mocked parameter is not an option because I'm writing a parameterized test using JUnitParams

approach 1:

```
  new MockUp<MyClass>()
  {
     @Mock
     public void $init(String a, String b)
     {
     }

     @Mock
     public void myMethod(String s)
     {
     }
  };
```

approach 2:

```
  new MockUp<MyClass>()
  {
     @Mock
     public void $init(String a, String b)
     {
     }
  };      

  new MockUp<MyClass>()
  {
     @Mock
     public void myMethod(String s)
     {
     }
  };
```

Comment: Yes, a MockUp subclass can have any (> 0) number of `@Mock` methods. You would need to show a complete failing test...

Comment: @Rogério your answer is correct and it seems I'm doing something else wrong, so I asked a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304793/how-to-mock-local-instance-when-using-jmockit-in-combination-with-junitparams-pa